# Why is the following block not thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, performance, java-stream

We have a Spring Boot application where we fetch data from a database and keep it in a concurrent Hashmap tempMap. Then we use it to fetch details based on the incoming keys. But keys are in the form of arrays. Now, once loaded we don't refresh the map until the scheduler hits. But we can see empty optional being returned but the map was never refreshed. The method is being accessed by many threads in the application. Seems some kind of memory leak is there. Please, anyone can help to point what might be the issue.

This is the function body accessed by many threads that throws No value present exception:

```
if (sender.length == 1) {
    return getSingle(sender[0]).get();
} else {
    return getMultiple(sender).get();
}
```

These are the implementations for functions:

```
private Optional<DummyClassEntity> getSingle(String value) {
    Optional<DummyClassEntity> dummyClass;
    dummyClass = Optional.of(tempMap.get(value));
    return dummyClass;
}

private Optional<DummyClassEntity> getMultiple(String[] values) {
    return Arrays.stream(values)
        .filter(value -> tempMap.containsKey(value))
        .findFirst()
        .map(s -> tempMap.get(s));
}
```

I tried using synchronized block. But that still impacts the performance. And this part is being used for an high performance application.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Is it that the map is not refreshed before fetching, or is it the performance issue?

Comment: @colouredmirrorball or supposed "memory leak". Really unclear.

Comment: You haven't given enough info for anyone to help you, but `getMultiple` contains a check-then-act. It's not atomic. It might contain the key when doing `filter`, but not when doing `get`.

Comment: @Michael Even worse than that - every single one of those chained method calls all have to be thread-safe.  And then what's apparently an underlying map of some type also has to be thread-safe.  All of that is in addition to the TOCTOU bug you pointed out.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Which chained calls? The stream operations? I don't see what would be unsafe about `Arrays.stream(values).map(tempMap::get).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst()`.

Comment: @Michael *I don't see what would be unsafe*  [Oh?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) "The array, assumed to be unmodified during use."  The very first call in the chain isn't thread-safe.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I've seen no reason from the question to assume that the arrays are necessarily shared across threads. The instance used for lookup may be a different from the instance stored in the map. Provided they're thread-local, it's fine.

Comment: @Michael  There's no evidence that is isn't being shared either.  Given the contents of the question, the posted code has the smell of a project where thread safety was not stringently enforced at all times.  The very first Javadoc lookup I did on the code revealed potential race conditions.  From what's been posted here so far, I believe everyone working on this project has a **HUGE** problem on their hands - they've written a multithreaded high-performance application without actually accounting for thread safety at every step, on every single code line.  IMO the entire code base is suspect.

Comment: @Michael I'm not making any assumptions.  Because it's never safe to assume anything in a complex multithreaded application - you never know when something that's only accessed by one thread at a time will suddenly be accessed by another.  Which is why I say everything **must** be thread-safe.  The questioner doesn't appear to know what's actually going on, and that's probably true for just about everyone working on this project.  They're all about to have a forced crash-course in writing thread-safe Java.

Comment: (cont) The question is fundamentally backwards - we don't need to find the thread-**unsafe** code.  The questioner (and everyone on this project) needs to go through the entire code base and **prove** everything is thread-safe with no regard to performance.  Because if it's wrong, it doesn't matter how fast it is.  They've likely coded themselves into a huge hole, and the only way out is to climb out one updated line of code at a time.  The sooner they get started, the sooner they'll be finished.  And if they think they can avoid that, they'll have bugs like this forever.

Comment: @Michael What about your *Which chained calls? The stream operations? I don't see what would be unsafe about `Arrays.stream(values)...`* You didn't even know `Arrays.stream()` isn't thread-safe. You're blindly assuming things are thread-safe, which is an *unsafe* assumption to make in a complex multithreaded application. I'm not "shitting on the entire team". The simple fact is the entire contents of the question - not just the code - are consistent with a lack of rigor in the development process. What's obnoxious is the questioner is probably a junior dev stuck with trying to fix this problem

Comment: (cont) Being a junior developer who has to come in and fix this problem in a large code base is more than a bit unfair to that developer.  This is most likely a problem the senior developers and system architects created, and there's no way a junior developer can fix individual race conditions in a code base that's fundamentally thread-**unsafe**, which the posted code sure has the characteristics of.

Comment: At the beginning, you are suggesting that your code is not thread safe, in other words, *broken*. At the end, you are saying “*But that still impacts the performance*” as if your concern was performance all the time. You should first decide what your problem is. As a hint: *as long as your code is broken, performance is entirely irrelevant*